# see all history of git

Tags: git

Let's say, my current git log is

commit3

commit2

commit1

I reset the head to commit2.

Now I want to go back to commit3, but I **forget** the sha-1 of commit3, so I want to look at the log , but "git log" will only show commit2, commit1, my question is how to reset to commit3 or let the log show also commit3 now?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`git reflog`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reflog.html) to find the old reference and pass it to `git log` directly. Note that the reflog is purged periodically, and old commits will be eventually deleted unless they're part of a branch - if you want to undo a commit but leave it in history, use [`git revert`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-revert.html) to undo them without removing them from history.

Comment: Or, if it's unpublished, just create a different branch at the commit to keep.

Answer (score 5):

The command

```
git reflog
```

will show you a list of SHAs that have been the HEAD. In other words, it shows a list of commits in the order that they have been checked out. In that list you will also see the syntax `HEAD@{1}`, `HEAD@{2}` etc. That is a way to address the previous HEADs.

I your case `git checkout HEAD@{1}` should check out commit3, because it was the HEAD before the current HEAD.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways :-

Classic : git reflog

Big Picture :)  git log --graph --decorate --oneline